# Standalone HTMLBars runtime compiler

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, htmlbars

I'm currently using Backbone.js as my front-end management library and am now looking for a template engine to go alongside it. Underscore/Lodash are great but not quite comprehensive enough.

Until/if I find a better client-side compiler, I'm using doT.js. It's great, but IDE and datasource support is lacking. With doT.js, compiling a template is as simple as can be:

```
<script src="js/dot.js"></script>
<script src="js/backbone.js"></script>

<script>
  var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: doT.template('<h1>{{=it.title}}</h1>');
  });
</script>
```

I love the additional features and power of HTMLBars and would like to use it in a very similar way, something like:

```
<script src="js/htmlbars.js"></script>
<script src="js/backbone.js"></script>

<script>
  var TestView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: HTMLBars.compile('<h1>{{title}}</h1>'); // or however HTMLBars would compile client-side
  });
</script>
```

The only *somewhat* standalone version I can find is [`ember-template-compiler.js`](http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember-template-compiler.js), though it looks like this still depends on Ember. I'm not sure if there's a way to, or someone already has, extracted this to a standalone version.

Is there somewhere I can download and include an `htmlbars.js` file or am I still stuck with Handlebars for the time being?